# How do I add an HTML attribute to a dynamically created build script in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

There are 4 scripts created by Angular when a project is built with `ng build --prod`. One of these is `main.js`. Is there any way I can dynamically 
attach an HTML attribute to the corresponding script tag in the `index.html` file after the build command is run?

The reason I am asking is because I am displaying some above-the-fold CSS which I'd like to remove when the `main.js` Angular script has finished loading. To do this, I want to attach the `onload` HTML attribute to the script. For example:

index.html:

```html
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript" onload="removeAboveTheFoldCSS()"></script>
```

If this isn't possible, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have `removeAboveTheFoldCSS()` just be the first thing that happens in main.js

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`--main.js--`

```
"use strict"
function removeAboveTheFoldCSS(){
  //logic
}
removeAboveTheFoldCSS()

// the rest of your JS code
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the native onLoad() method on body like this, as this will be called when all the static content is loaded:-

```
<body onload="removeAboveTheFoldCSS()"
```